# Why the method "SendKeys" doesn't work with Windows Phone WebDriver?

Tags: windows-phone-8, sendkeys, remotewebdriver

I use Windows Phone and a RemoteWebDriver but when I try to use a "SendKeys" method, I got this error :

```
Unexpected error. Call could not be fullfield. JavaScript injection failed.
```

Example :

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ID")).SendKeys("string");
```

Best regards,

Xialuna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a solution.

I create a new function like this :

```
public void javascriptSendKeys(String id, String value)
{
    String script = "document.getElementById(\"" + id + "\").value=\"" + value + "\" ";
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
}
```

And I use it when I need to use a SendKeys method.

It's work fine for me.

Have a nice day !

Xialuna